# How do I prevent water from leaking from my bath faucet when the shower is on?

Tags: faucet, bathtub

When the water is diverted to the shower, water leaks back from inside the faucet towards the wall.  How do I fix it?

Comment: @steven: to me, this sounds more like a leak from the valve rather than a broken diverter. user15809: can you add more detail to your question to help us diagnose the problem. Thanks.